# error after compilation in C

Tags: c

when i compile i get the following error, why i get this error every thing looks fine.have given just a part of the code.

error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

```
main()
{
int clf_cnt,key;
struct classifier clsf,*clsf_ptr;
int choice;
printf("Creation of B tree for node %d\n",M);
while(1)
{
    printf("1.Insert\n");
    printf("2.Display\n");
    printf("3.Quit\n");
    printf("Enter your choice : ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    switch(choice)
            {

                    case 1:
                            printf("Enter the rules : ");
                            for(clf_cnt = 0;clf_cnt < M;clf_cnt++)
                                    {
                             error line:       clsf_ptr = &clsf[clf_cnt];
```

but i have declared

```
    struct node
    {
    int n; 
    int keys[M-1]; 
    struct node *p[M]; 
    struct classifier clsf[M-1]; 
    }*root=NULL;
```

then how should insert data to this array of structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to index a `struct` here: `clsf[clf_cnt]`. Structs can't be indexed this way, only arrays and pointers.

So writing e.g. `clsf_ptr[clf_cnt]` instead would make your compiler happy :-) However, then you must also initialize that pointer to actually point to an existing array of `struct classifier` instances, prior to using it. Otherwise you get undefined behaviour (i.e. most likely your program will crash).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `clsf[clf_cnt]`. `clsf` is not a pointer nor array.

Answer (score 1):

Because `clsf` is of type `struct classifier` which isn't an array or a pointer, exactly what compiles has told you.  You cannot use `[]` operator on a `struct` in C.

Answer (score 1):

`clsf` is declared as a single `struct`, but you treat it as if it was an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think the offending line should be `clsf_ptr[clf_cnt];`.